# Python Tkinter typing suggestions

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to design a text editor that makes word suggestions from a lexicon as the user types. I am using Tkinter for the interface and was wondering if it is possible to anchor the list to the word the user is typing, something like Notepad++.

Here's a link as example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huSS5.png

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do this, but I think it's possible to construct from scratch using an Entry and a Listbox. You probably need to use `.place` to manage the Listbox's geometry, since (AFAIK) that's the only way to get it to float on top of any widgets that are below the Entry.

Comment: Calling `.bbox('insert')` on your Text will give you (X, Y, width, height) of the character at the insertion point, which could be used to position your popup.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Is that really all you are asking?